# Implementing a Google Map with UItableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to implement a google map inside a UItableviewCell component. The way I am doing this is to define a GMSMapView within the protoype cell, and then using the dequeueReusableCell method i'm configuring the map cell. However, any change i try to apply fails (such as adding markers, camera, zoom, etc.). Does anybody have any information about this issue?

Code reference:

```
class UITenderInfoMapCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var subView: GMSMapView!

override func awakeFromNib() {

    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.initMap()

}



/**
    Init blank map when initializing a MapCell, waypoints, directions, etc can be loaded later.
**/
func initMap() {

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 1.285, longitude: 103.848, zoom: 12)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
    self.subView = mapView


}
```

Comment: some code would be helpful, we don't read minds..

Comment: any change i try to apply fails? What do you mean by that? Do your app crashes or changes not visible in UI?

Comment: @Matt changes are not visible in the UI, i just keep getting a blank map.

Comment: Are you using google map sdk by installing pod ? @Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do following steps to add MapView to TableViewCell

1. Take one UIView in your custom Tableviewcell and give the class name as "GMSmapView" to that UIView
2. Make sure to connect delegate method of Mapview.
3. In your ViewController import "GoogleMaps" along with delegate "GMSMapViewDelegate".
4. Make outlet for MapView like this for your created TableViewCell:

> ```
> import UIKit
>
> import GoogleMaps
>
> class MapviewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
>
>
> @IBOutlet weak var mapviewObj: GMSMapView!
>
> override func awakeFromNib() {
>     super.awakeFromNib()
>     // Initialization code
> }
>
> override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
>     super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
>
>     // Configure the view for the selected state
> }
>
> }
> ```

5. Add Following code in "cellForRowAt"

   ```
           let cell = tableviewObj.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MapviewTableViewCell

           let marker = GMSMarker()

           let lat = Double("13.063754")
           let long = Double("80.24358699999993")
           marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat!,long!)

           ///View for Marker
           let DynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:50, height:50))
           DynamicView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

           //Pin image view for Custom Marker
           let imageView = UIImageView()
           imageView.frame  = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:50, height:35)
           imageView.image = UIImage(named:"LocationPin")

           //Adding pin image to view for Custom Marker
           DynamicView.addSubview(imageView)

           UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(DynamicView.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
           DynamicView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
           let imageConverted: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
           UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

           marker.icon = imageConverted
           marker.map = cell.mapviewObj

           cell.mapviewObj.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: marker.position, zoom: 11)

           return cell
   ```

**NOTE:Here I am giving this some extra code to add your custom marker using "DynamicView". If you don`t want to add custom marker, you can skip those code. Also Don`t forget to configure require settings for google maps from google developer account and add respective key to you appdelegate e.g.**

```
let key = "keep you key here"
GMSServices.provideAPIKey(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an outlet for GMSMapView as you did, nothing more. I skipped your `initMap()` method.

And in `ViewController` `cellForRowAt` and it works fine for me.

```
let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.483682, longitude: -0.091991))
marker.map = cell?.subView
```

What was your issue exactly?