# Swift GMSMarker icon in the top left corner of the view

Tags: swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager

Title is pretty self explanatory. I've tried calling it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989913/gmsmarker-icon-in-the-top-left-corner-of-the-view-ios/45049574#45049574) but it's given me no joy.

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    mapView.mapType = .normal
    mapView.settings.zoomGestures   = true
    mapView.settings.tiltGestures   = true
    mapView.settings.rotateGestures = true
    mapView?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    locationManager.delegate = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if(locationManager.location != nil){
        centerMapOnLocation(location: locationManager.location!)
    }
}

func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation)
{
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: zoom)
        mapView?.animate(to: camera)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've figured out a fix so I'm putting it here in case someone else has this issue.

I changed from using `mapView?.animate` to `GMSCameraPosition.camera` and it seems to be working fine.

```
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation)
{
    let target = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude)
    mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: target, zoom: zoom)
}
```

Comment: Me thinks the iOS docs need to be updated! this is definitely the answer.